# smooth streaming .wmv files

Tags: streaming, smoothing

Windows Media Services is not supported on Windows Server 2012 onwards  Can wmv be streamed using IIS smooth streaming (or even any 3rd party solutions)?

Can Media Services can be made available on Windows Server 2012 R2 somehow?

Please suggest any other solution that satisfies 3 conditions 
o   (1) Based on Windows Server 2012 R2, 
o   (2) using wmv as media format 
o   (3) Is a streaming solution

Answer (score 0):

WMVs cannot be Smooth Streamed, smooth streaming requires the media files to be in a fragmented format which is not supported with WMV.

You can transcode the WMV files into the ISMV format (fragmented MP4) which will allow you to Smooth Stream your files.